# Models neo4j with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I am working on a rails-neo4j project and i have a problem (many problems ;). My database model is :
Knowledge -APPROVED_BY-> Bibliography -HAVE_GOT-> Publication and Knowlegde -RELATION-> Knowlegde. I write the next models files :

active_node.rb :

```
class ActiveNode 
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  include Neo4j::Timestamps
end
```

active_rel.rb :

```
class ActiveRel 
  include Neo4j::ActiveRel
  include Neo4j::Timestamps
end
```

approved_by.rb :

```
class ApprovedBy < ActiveRel
  from_class :Knowledge
  to_class :Bibliography
  type 'APPROVED_BY'
end
```

bibliography.rb :

```
class Bibliography < ActiveNode
  property :name, type: String
  has_many :in, :publications, rel_class: :HaveGot
  has_one :out, :knowlegde, rel_class: :ApprovedBy
end
```

have_got.rb :

```
class HaveGot < ActiveRel
  from_class :Bibliography
  to_class   :Publication
  type 'HAVE_GOT'
end
```

knowledge.rb :

```
class Knowledge < ActiveNode
  property :title, type: String
  property :content, type: String
  has_one :in, :bibliography, rel_class: :ApprovedBy
  has_many :both, :knowledges, rel_class: :Relation
end
```

publication.rb :

```
class Publication < ActiveNode
  property :link, type: String
  property :author, type: String
  property :title, type: String
  has_one :out, :bibliography, rel_class: :HaveGot
end
```

relation.rb :

```
class Relation < ActiveRel
  from_class :Knowledge
  to_class :Knowledge
  type 'RELATION'
  property :name, type: String
end
```

To make this projet i am reading : https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/index.html
and : https://neo4j.com/developer/ruby-course/.

After run all servers and migration i try to go to localhost:3000/knowledges :

```
Started GET "/knowledges/" for ::1 at 2017-03-21 17:21:41 +0100

 HTTP REQUEST: 10ms GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint (0 bytes)
 HTTP REQUEST: 3ms GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/constraint (0 bytes)
 HTTP REQUEST: 2ms GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/schema/index (0 bytes)
 Neo4j::Migrations::SchemaMigration 
  MATCH (n:`Neo4j::Migrations::SchemaMigration`)
  RETURN n 
 HTTP REQUEST: 7ms POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit (1 bytes)
Processing by KnowledgesController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms
```

And when i try to create new Knowledge by rails console i have :

```
SyntaxError: /Users/blondeaudamien/projets/myapp/app/models/knowledge.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
?:bibliography, rel_class: :ApprovedBy
                              ^
/Users/blondeaudamien/projets/myapp/app/models/knowledge.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
, :knowledges, rel_class: :Relation
```

Anyone can help me please ? Thx !